# CHARINDEX equivalent in DB2

Tags: select, query, db2

I am trying to select the domain from the column where I have email addresses.

For example, I have a table email_table and a column email with email addresses as below.

```
johndoe@gmail.com
jhefid@yahoo.com
ipw@gmx.com
```

Expected result

```
gmail.com
yahoo.com
gmx.com
```

Here is the query I tried with CHARINDEX that works in SQL Server but not in DB2.

```
select CHARINDEX('@', email) from email_table
```

Comment: INSTR, INSTR2, INSTR4, INSTRB, LOCATE, LOCATE_IN_STRING... select one which is more safe for your task.

Answer (score 3):

It's `LOCATE` (in DB2) which is equivalent to `CHARINDEX` in SQL Server.

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000820.html) is the complete description of it with example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In Db2 (for LUW) V11.1 and above, you can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061492.html

E.g.

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(c,'@(.*)$',1,1,'',1) 
FROM TABLE(
    VALUES
     ('johndoe@gmail.com')
    ,('jhefid@yahoo.com')
    ,('ipw@gmx.com')
) AS t(c)
```

returns

```
1                
-----------------
gmail.com        
yahoo.com        
gmx.com          

  3 record(s) selected.
```